# How to retrieve frames from video4linux in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, video4linux

I'm trying to save pixel data from webcam feed.

How do I save frames from video4linux with c++?

Comment: Here you go buddy: http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/videobook.pdf